# Move Folders Containing Certain File

Tags: windows-7, file-management, windows-search

I'm trying to sort out a bunch of folders in Windows 7. I have a bunch of folders and some contain a file index.txt and some don't. What I want to do is move the folders that do have index.txt into a different directory so I separate the ones that do and do not contain a file called index.txt

How can I do this? I tried using the built-in Windows 7 search but it doesn't seem to do what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From command line:

```
for /d %f in ("D:\A Bunch of Folders\*") do @if exist "%~f\index.txt" move "%~f" "EC:\With indexes"
```

This example will check all folders under `D:\A Bunch of Folders` and move the ones with indexes to `E:\With indexes`. Adjust to match your real paths, of course.

If you want the command to work recursively (that is, to also check subfolders, sub-sub-folders, and so on), add `/r` (`for /r /d`).

Comment: I always think your avatar looks like a sleeping tiger.

Comment: Thanks worked great! Just wanted to point out that in your code you have the output folder as `"EC:\With indexes"` instead of `"E:\With indexes"`